# Django models with default (automatic) primary key - upate vs save entries

Tags: python, django, primary-key

My models.py includes several fields. The primary key is by default, set automatically by Django.

I have a Django crontab that attempts to update each entry on a regular basis, but can no longer save. (Until recently, I had manually set the primary key based on one of these fields.)

Could someone suggest how to get around this. For each entry, I'd like to be able to update each of the declared fields and create if non-existent.

**I was under the impression that save does both create or update as neccessary**

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    init = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fullid = models.CharField(max_length=30) <--- used to be primary_key=True

Crontab (pseudocode)
    for x in list:
        try: 
           entry = init='abc', last='def', fullid='xyz'
           entry.save()

        except: 'unable to update.' <-- I'm now hitting the except all the time.
```

Comment: Can you give some code samples? It's a little hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do, and why what you're doing isn't working.

Comment: Sounds like `get_or_create` should help you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: @Karmel =- just added code example.

Comment: This syntax: `entry = init='abc', last='def', fullid='xyz'` doesn't look right, making it particularly difficult to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @arie - does get_or_create update when the entry exists? couldn't find that part in the docs

Comment: @thong: it does not do any updates. It either gets it or it creates it. You are right about save doing both a create and update as necc. But from your pseudo code you seem to be creating a new entry each time and callig save. This will error on your unique key if dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like that:

```
try: 
    abc = ABC.objects.get(fullid=id) 
except ABC.DoesNotExist: 
    ABC.objects.create(params)
else:
    abc.field = value
    abc.save()
```

Never ever use `try: ... except: ...` because this way you don't even know what have failed inside. Catch only "awaited" exceptions which you do know how to process. Or, if you want it to be bulletproof and unstoppable - at least display catched exception info.

Comment: +1 for addressing the blanket try except catch all. Also, get_or_create and checking the created bool should make this even shorter with no try except needed

Comment: haha.  yes! @jdi and i were talking about the bad habit i've picked up with the try and excepts

Comment: Actually, I prefer 2 more code lines here. First, with `get_or_create`  we'll need to set params and `save()` one more time in `create` case. Second, `try...except` look more pythonic to me. Third, if some of fields are `NOT NULL`, then `create` will fail.